# 隹 colloquial name

Tags: radicals

To start, let's note that the colloquial names of the radicals different from those of the dictionary differ. For example if I asked a native Chinese person what is 彳, they would certainly respond 双人旁, but the dictionary says it's chi4.

Next, let's note that it's possible to have more than one colloquial name. For example, 亻is called 单人旁，and 单立人 even though the former is vastly more common.

With these considerations in mind, I call upon the readers of this question to collect a list of all the colloquial names for the radical 隹。

Thank you.

Comment: (1) Radicals (部首) don't have unique names; you haven't listed anything that suggests these names are unique to radicals. Please note that the names you've listed end in 旁, which is short for 偏旁. 偏旁 **is not** 部首. (2) 彳 is a standalone character, used in the archaic phrase 彳亍 (`chi4 chu4`).

Comment: see Understandable names of the radicals https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22095/understandable-names-of-the-radicals esp. comments 1.2, quoting 教学汉字规范手册, "亻：单立人"

Comment: @drooze 单立人doesn't end in 旁. There

Comment: @droooze 单立人doesn't end in 旁. There are others like 宀 (读宝盖) which also don't. Please explain the difference between 部首 and 偏旁 - why is only one the translation of "radical"? How do you translate the other?

Comment: Radicals are dictionary headers. The only time 部首 is used are listing characters under dictionaries, and there are a very limited number of 部首. You seem to be speaking about generic components that characters are comprised of, which are only called 偏旁. Please don’t mix these two terms up, it gets very confusing if you do.

Comment: @psitae [Discussion on the use of the words 部首 and 偏旁 in describing Chinese characters + translation](https://redd.it/wl0by9).

Answer (score 3):

There’s a list here you might want to look at: http://www.jiantizi.com/help/bushoumingchen.htm

> 形状 名称
>
> 隹  隹字旁

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

隹字边、隹字旁、隹部 and possibly many more.

---

## Long answer

The (false) pretense behind this question seems to be: because some radicals do not just have a name but they themselves are already a valid hanzi, we should list all names for this radical.  This question is complicated, so I'll respond it from two perspectives.

### The [GF 0014—2009](http://www.moe.gov.cn/ewebeditor/uploadfile/2015/01/13/20150113090318445.pdf)

Well, there is nothing inherently wrong with gathering a list of names for the radicals.  In fact, this question is so intriguing that it drew full attention from both the Ministry of Education of the P.R.C. and the State Language Commission, who jointly published the [GF 0014—2009](http://www.moe.gov.cn/ewebeditor/uploadfile/2015/01/13/20150113090318445.pdf) standard, titled "Specification of Common Modern Chinese Character Components and Component Names".

We'll take a sneak peak of this standard.  In subsection 6.3.2 on page 4 we find

> 6.3.2　**有多种俗称的**非成字部件，采用**一个**含义明确、比较通行的俗称命名。
>   　　　　例如：“纟”俗称有“绞丝旁”“绞丝”“孪绞丝”“乱绞丝”等，选用“绞丝旁”；
>   　　　　　　　“彳”俗称有“双立人”“双人旁”等，选用“双立人”。

Emphasis mine.  Literal translation:

> 6.3.2 For a component of dependent character formation **with multiple common terms**, adopt and name it after **one** clearly defined and generally used common term.  For example: Common terms of "纟" include "绞丝旁", "绞丝", "孪绞丝", "乱绞丝", etc.  Select and use "绞丝旁";  common terms of "彳" include "双立人", "双人旁", etc.  Select and use "双立人".

The gems here is not only the definition, but also these concrete examples of names people have given to these components.  There are more such examples but the standard is unable to exhaust all of them.

Another sneak peek: From page 7 to page 29, the standard lists common components as well as their terms.  On page 14 we see that 人 and 亻 are listed next to each other.  The common term for 人 is simply 人 while 亻 is listed as 单立人.  There are other such examples and I encourage you to skim the standard.

### The radicals as hanzi

The beloved and often amusing character [彳](https://hanyu.baidu.com/shici/detail?pid=2a4cd57097a58b2235231791be0ceb5d&from=kg0&highlight=%E5%83%8F%E6%88%91%E4%B8%80%E6%A0%B7%E5%9C%B0%20%E9%BB%98%E9%BB%98%E5%BD%B3%E4%BA%8D%E7%9D%80) is a valid hanzi that had found its way into Chinese literature, some of which are taught in highschool, e.g.

> 撑着油纸伞
>   像我一样
>   像我一样地
>   默默彳亍着
>   冷漠、
>   凄清，
>   又惆怅
>
> ——节选自[戴望舒《雨巷》](https://hanyu.baidu.com/shici/detail?pid=2a4cd57097a58b2235231791be0ceb5d&from=kg0&highlight=%E5%83%8F%E6%88%91%E4%B8%80%E6%A0%B7%E5%9C%B0%20%E9%BB%98%E9%BB%98%E5%BD%B3%E4%BA%8D%E7%9D%80)

Yes—that is **not** “默默**行**着” you see there.  You can refer to 彳 as 双立人 or 双人旁, or simply as 彳部.  They're all acceptable per the standard.

As to why they're given these common terms, note that it can be due to many reasons.  To me, 亻 is the variant of 人 which looks like a person with a leg up (hence the name 单立人), while in 彳 one 亻 is standing behind the other 亻 in the front, which makes it look like two people are standing (hence the name 双立人).

Tautologically speaking, names other than the standard **are** not standard, so they're often less used and lesser known, but it doesn't stop the general mass from using them.  In that regard, radicals such as 隹 (隹字边) possibly has lesser-known terms, and it is not practical to compile such lists unless we acquire more assistance, which the SE model is totally fit for.

Reference: [现代常用字部件及部件名称规范 GF 0014—2009](http://www.moe.gov.cn/ewebeditor/uploadfile/2015/01/13/20150113090318445.pdf)